# TextTrack LanguageCode parameter in Tracks.BeginCreateOrUpdateAsync

Tags: c#, azure-media-services

How to set the TrackBase parameter with LanguageCode when uploading track with `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media`v6.0.0?

Adding track works, but languageCode remains empty

```
await client.Tracks.BeginCreateOrUpdateAsync(
    config.ResourceGroup,
    config.AccountName,
    foundAsset.Name,
    "M0508826_FI.vtt",
    new TextTrack("M0508826_FI.vtt", "suomi", "fi")
);
```

```
 {
            "name": "M0508826_FI.vtt",
            "id": "/subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/.../assets/.../tracks/M0508826_FI.vtt",
            "type": "Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/assets/tracks",
            "properties": {
                "track": {
                    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.TextTrack",
                    "fileName": "M0508826_FI.vtt",
                    "displayName": "suomi",
                    "languageCode": "",
                    "playerVisibility": "Visible"
                },
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
            }
        }
```

Tried to set languageCode also to "fi-FI", but result is same. It works fine if the track is added via REST API.

REST HTTP POST body being

```
{
    "properties": {
        "track": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Media.TextTrack",
            "displayName": "suomi",
            "fileName": "M0508826_FI.vtt",
            "languageCode": "fi",
            "playerVisibility": "Visible"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself, as I found the answer hidden in the comments of the TS sample file at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/f614109b34bc5ef8e7a4be074b8e30c99f3fc7c4/Assets/add-WebVTT-tracks.ts#L138.

You need to include the language in the WEBVTT file as follows:

```
// AMS supports uploading both .vtt files and .ttml files in the IMSC1 text profile (basically no images in base64!)
// The desired language should be set in the head of the vtt file in the following format:
//
// WEBVTT
// Language: en-us
```

Answer (score 1):

That one tripped me up as well when our SDK update came out.

I wrote this sample here - not sure if you saw it already.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Assets/add-WebVTT-tracks.ts#L156

```
 await mediaServicesClient.tracks.beginCreateOrUpdateAndWait(
    resourceGroup,
    accountName,
    outputAsset.name,
    "English", 
    {
        name: "English",
        track: {
          odataType:"#Microsoft.Media.TextTrack",
          displayName:"English",
          fileName: filename,
          hlsSettings:{
            default:true,
            forced:true,
            //Allowed values for HLS characteristics, as per HLS rfc(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216.html#page-54)
            characteristics:"public.accessibility.transcribes-spoken-dialog"
          },
          playerVisibility:"Visible" 
        }
    },
    {
      updateIntervalInMs: 1000,
    } 
  )
```

Comment: Yes, I've used that sample but failed to notice the comment explaining how it should be done. :)